# Python: Unresolved reference in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Following a 'batch-process files' tutorial in the app 'Mimo' and I've written the code as I should according to the tut, but I'm getting an error. Been doing some searching but I honestly don't understand the errors. According to the app this code should work so i can rename photo files in my folder.. Thanks in advance let me know if I'm doing something wrong regarding stackoverflow question ethics as it's my first.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
folder = r"C:\Users\xXind_000\Desktop\olympus gold"
location = input("Photo location:")
files = os.listdir(folder)
for filename in files:
    if not filename.startswith('.'):
        file = os.path.join(folder, "P8050043.JPG")
        m_time = os.path.getmtime(file)
        real_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(m_time)
        f_time = datetime.strftime(real_time, "%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        new_filename = f_time + "_" + location ".png" #The error appears at the f_time and location variables
        new_file = os.path.join(folder, new_filename)
        os.rename(file, new_file)
```

This is the error I'm getting in the new_filename variable on the third last  line (I'm getting it on both the f_time variable and location variable in the new_filename variable):

> Unresolved reference 'f_time' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

Comment: Which reference is not resolved? Please add the complete error message.

Comment: At the 'f_time' and 'location' variables under the new_filename variable in third last line.